What exactly does the parameter "real_field=True" in the sympy constructor of a quaternion mean?
In the sympy documentation about quatenions https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/algebras.html#sympy.algebras.Quaternion the quatenion constructor is defined as:
class sympy.algebras.Quaternion(a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, real_field=True, norm=None)
What is the meaning of keyword argument real_field=True?

It was first added in this 2017 commit with the name real_elements and was renamed to real_field in the next commit.
The former also introduced this check, which was removed 2 days later:
if any(i.is_real is False for i in [a, b, c, d]):
    real_elements = False

Looking at the code, the parameter was probably used to signal that all coefficients are real numbers.

Quaternions are written as a+bi+cj+dk where a,b,c,d are numbers in a field and 1,i,j,k are the unit quaternions. real_field controls whether sympy expects a,b,c,d to be real numbers or complex numbers (i.e. real_field=True means they should be reals, real_field=False means they can be complex numbers).
Taken from https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/algebras.html#sympy.algebras.Quaternion, there is an example called Quaternions over complex fields
from sympy import Quaternion
from sympy import symbols, I
x = symbols('x')
q1 = Quaternion(x, x**3, x, x**2, real_field = False)
q2 = Quaternion(3 + 4*I, 2 + 5*I, 0, 7 + 8*I, real_field = False)

So you can see when a,b,c,d are complex numbers, real_field should be False.
